# Express hbs does not work

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine

I know this post is a kinda dupplicate, 
but I can't find out where I'm wrong.

/// my app.js //

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('views'));
//
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    //res.sendFile('/index.html');
    res.render('index',{title :"page index"});

  });

app.listen(3000);
```

Here my ./views/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Index</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .hbs as the extension.

Try to rename your `/views/index.html` to `/views/index.hbs`

and change it in the code as follows

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Apparently hbs wants .hbs to be used.

Tip: hbs hbs does not look so good to me, you can take a look at swig: http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs

Comment: .hbs worked for me. 
Replaced 
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
by
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', require('hbs').__express);
Swig looks like much more simple. Will have a look on soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

> app.set('view engine', 'html');
>   app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);

Instead of the this

> app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
>   app.set('views', 'views');
>   app.set('view engine', 'html');